# Trouble using videoscale in gstreamer when using a rtph264pay sink for rtsp output

Tags: ubuntu, gstreamer, rtsp, rtsp-server

I'm passing the following pipeline string to the gst_rtsp_media_factory_set_launch function to create an rtsp output:

```
souphttpsrc location=[some https url.m3u8] ! decodebin ! videoscale ! video/x-raw,width=1080,height=720 ! x264enc ! rtph264pay name=pay0 pt=96
```

So long as I set the height and width to match the original video, in this case 720 x 480, everything works. However if I actually try to change the size, it fails.

I get many errors from GST_DEBUG=2, but the first one is this:

```
0:00:08.560644403 63781 0x7ff24403ad20 ERROR       vaapivideomemory gstvaapivideomemory.c:254:map_vaapi_memory: failed to make image current
0:00:08.560799168 63781 0x7ff24403ad20 ERROR                default video-frame.c:168:gst_video_frame_map_id: failed to map video frame plane 0
0:00:08.560900236 63781 0x7ff24403ad20 ERROR                x264enc gstx264enc.c:2498:gst_x264_enc_handle_frame:<x264enc0> Failed to map frame
```

The same pipeline works if I substitute videotestsrc as the source; additionally, oddly enough, I'm about 90% sure this worked on a different PC I no longer have access to.